# Replace string in text without onClick Function

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on embedding YT videos into the video component view using this tutorial as a guide:

https://reactnativecode.com/find-replace-string-text-component/

It works but I have to replace part of the string manually to display it on the page when I paste in the URL.

Raw Youtube URL
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ZhJjRBnWYk`

Manually typed
`https://www.youtube.com/embed/6ZhJjRBnWYk`

For aesthetic there's no submit button so when the url is pasted in, it automatically renders the video. Normally, the onClick would handle the fixURLString function.

I'm trying to replace the string but it's not working because I'm not sure how to handle the fixURLString without a button as shown in the tutorial.

```
export default class VideoEmbed extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      embeds: [],
      url: '',
    }
  }

  ...
    onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })
  }

  fixUrlString = () => {
    const urlString = this.state.url.toString()
    const newText = urlString.replace('/watch?v=', '/embed/')
    this.setState({ url: newText })
  }

  ...
            <div className="upload-image-box">
            <form>
              <input
                name="url"
                type="text" 
                placeholder="paste YouTube embed code here"
                value={this.state.url}
                onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
              />
            </form>
          </div>

 ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call `fixUrlString` inside onChange with typed url, and set the state for already transformed string.

```
 onChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const fixedString = this.fixUrlString(e.target.value)
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: fixedString,
      url: fixedString
    })
  }

  fixUrlString = (original) => {
    const urlString = original.toString()
    return urlString.replace('/watch?v=', '/embed/')
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! This fixed my issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `fixUrlString` function to take your URL and simply return the new URL instead of calling setState within your function. This is known as a pure function. (A function which takes input and returns an output without modifying any data outside that function.)

Like this:

```
fixUrlString = (urlString) => {
    const newText = urlString.replace('/watch?v=', '/embed/');
    return newText;
}
```

Now you can simple call `setState` anywhere in your component and fix your url using that function.

Using your `onChange` as an example:

```
this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: this.fixUrlString(e.target.value),
});
```